# Recursive largestS integers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int* m = new int [d1*d2];
```

This is my array.

```
 for ( j = 0; j < d2; j++ )
{       for ( i = j; i < d1*d2; i +=d2){
         cout << *(m+i);
       }
  cout << endl;
}
```

And by using that i can group and print largest integer in each column if i think it as a multidimensional array.

Hard to explain what i want to do. I'll try giving an example.

Assume my input is 1 4 2 5 2 1 0 3 4

Output would be

```
1 5 0

4 2 3

2 1 4
```

I only want  the largest integer and keep listing the following largest integers  behind of that integer.

For first row i only want 5, 0

For second row i want 4  and 3.

For third row i want only 4.

Output would be:

> 5, 0, 4, 3, 4

Comment: I think you should try this. Instead of workin on columns. Just transpose the Matrix. Work on rows. Things will be simpler. Then transpose again if you need it.

Comment: for example for this case you will have a vector of vectors. Then you find the max of one row or vector you list all elements after it. And then you repeat for the next vector.

Comment: I mixed rows with columns fixed that.

Comment: "I only want to the largest integer" is a fragment (missing a verb). please add the verb.  Can you add the output you actually want to see?

Comment: Your sample output for the first column doesn't *seem* to mesh with what you're *almost* asking for. It should/could include `5,0` for the first "row" (which is actually a column), assuming something resembling logic is being used in this algorithm. Determining the largest integer in each column is easy enough (and would yield `5,4,4`). You need to explain *far* better exactly what *"... and keep listing the following largest integers behind of that integer."* ***means***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `a[]` contains your row, it looks like what you want is:

```
int i = column_count - 1;
deque<int> largests_list;
largests_list.push_front(a[i]);
int largest_found = a[i];

while (i-- > 0) {
    if (a[i] > largest_found) {
       largests_list.push_front(a[i]);
       largest_found = a[i];   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what he means, but re-reading the question I think you might be right.

Answer (score 0):

Try two inner loops (inside the first):

```
int largest = m[j];
for (i = j + 1; i < d1*d2; i+=d2)
{
   largest = max(largest, m[i]);
}
for (i = j; i < d1*d2; i+=d2)
{
   if (m[i] == largest)
   {
      cout << largest--;
   }
}
```